# Angular 2 - Click to edit form fields

Tags: forms, angular

I want to replace label with input textbox and vice versa by clicking a button in Angular 2. I knowi have to use ngIf of somekind, but i am a little bit confused on how to do.

HTML:

```
<form>
<div class="information">
  <label *ngIf="editMode">{{textValue}}</label>
  <input *ngIf="editMode" [ngModel]="name">
  <button (click)="editMode=true">Edit</button>
  <button (click)="editMode=false">Save</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: This looks good, what's the current situation?

Comment: Replace with what?

Comment: What i want is the answer on this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37404746/replacing-label-with-input-textbox-and-vice-versa-by-clicking-a-button-in-angula

But that is angular 1 and i am using angular 2 and ng-show and ng-hide is not part of angular 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing you need to add to one of your `*ngIf`'s, is exclamation mark:

```
<label *ngIf="!editMode">{{textValue}}</label>
```

which means that label is shown when `editMode` is false. The exclamation mark is the NOT operator, which is used as truth tests on a variable. More here: [What does an exclamation mark before a variable mean in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491491/what-does-an-exclamation-mark-before-a-variable-mean-in-javascript)

Comment: I tried that, and that gave me: https://plnkr.co/edit/B6o0yydz0iUEVSKKjY4c?p=preview

What i want is to change the name label to a input field when pressing the edit button

Comment: Well, you are using `ng-show` and `ng-hide`. You are supposed to use *ngIf like you have in your question :)

Comment: @VarunBalachanthiran that's not a valid plunker, here's a plunker of what AJT_82 means: https://plnkr.co/edit/U1poqbiD8uLmk4Bw8AOM

Comment: Oh, your right, sorry, it works now. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @VarunBalachanthiran you can/should accept an answer if it helped you solving your issue: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135826/346766

Comment: @echonax Thanks man, I was just about to a plunker myself, but you, sir, were very kind! :P

Comment: @AJT_82 :D no problem!