# How to achieve this input box edit save functionality in Angular 4

Tags: input, save, label, edit

[image]I want to achieve the same functionality in Angular 4

[Replacing label with input textbox and vice versa by clicking a button in AngularJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37404746/replacing-label-with-input-textbox-and-vice-versa-by-clicking-a-button-in-angula)

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

It works basically the same, just use ***ngIf** for conditional rendering and **(click)** to handle the click event. **editMode** has to be a property in your component.ts file.

```
<form>
 <label *ngIf='!editMode'>{{name}}</label>
 <input *ngIf='editMode' [(ngModel)]="name" name='name'>
 <button (click)='editMode=true'>Edit</button>
 <button (click)='editMode=false'>Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: i dont want 2 buttons ( edit and save ). I want to replace edit with save once i click on Save

Comment: try this:<button (click)='editMode=!editMode'>{{editMode?"Save":"Edit"}}</button> this will start in the mode corresponding to whatever you set "editMode" to on initialization and change on each click. I just had two button in the solution as it was a modified version of the link you posted.